# What can be said about a linear transformation if there is a basis where its matrix is symmetric?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

What can be said about a linear transformation if there is a basis where its matrix is symmetric?

And how about the opposite direction? That is, if we have a symmetric matrix, what can be said about it as a linear transformation.

Thank you!

Comment: if a symmetric matrix has real entries, its eigenvalues are real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider to start the set of Hermitian matrices. It will be relevant since a matrix that has only real entries is Hermitian if and only if it is symmetric, and a real and symmetric matrix is a large special case of Hermitian matrices and likewise a large special case of symmetric matrices.

We have the following results:

Every Hermitian matrix is a normal matrix.

The sum of any two Hermitian matrices is Hermitian.

The inverse of an invertible Hermitian matrix is Hermitian as well.

The finite-dimensional spectral theorem says that any Hermitian matrix can be diagonalized by a unitary matrix, and that the resulting diagonal matrix has only real entries. This implies that all eigenvalues of a Hermitian matrix A with dimension n are real, and that A has n linearly independent eigenvectors.

The product of two Hermitian matrices A and B is Hermitian if and only if $AB = BA$.

$A^{n}$ is Hermitian if A is Hermitian and n is an integer.

If A and B are Hermitian, then $ABA$ is also Hermitian.

The determinant of a Hermitian matrix is real.

There are even more things you can say about Hermitian matrices but now is a good time to stop.